# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade Too many entries (66530)

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-delivery

Gradle build fails for Dynamic Feature module when minify is enabled with this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pal-phonepe-application:mergeInsidePhonePeStageInternalClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Too many entries (66530)
```

it works fine if minify is disabled..

Comment: Same error, do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found an answer. the issue with `zipflinger` it is internally used by android build tools to package APK.

The solution is to move to Android Gradle Plugin v4.0.0+.
It worked for me.